# how to count time from two or more time

Tags: php

```
$date1 = "01:45:54"; 

$date2 = "01:16:07"; 

    $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) + strtotime($date1)); 
    
    $hours   = floor(($diff / (60))/ (60)); 
    
    $minuts  = floor(($diff - $hours*60*60)/ 60); 
    
    $seconds = floor(($diff - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60)); 
    
    printf("%d hours, %d minuts\n, %d seconds\n", $hours, $minuts, $seconds);
```

**result 885685 hours, 2 minuts , 1 seconds (wrong)**
i want result **3 hours, 2 minuts , 1 seconds**

Thank you in Advance

Comment: You're adding the values. I imagine you want subtraction.

Comment: i want addition

Comment: 1. Then why is the variable named "diff"? 2. Then you don't want to use date functions at all. `strtotime()` implicitly adds the current day and returns a unix timestamp. It only works for diff because of several coincidences. 3. Parse the durations into seconds yourself and use your existing math.

Comment: What is the *meaning* of `3 hours 2 minutes and 1 second`?

Comment: 01:45:54
+
01:16:07
=
03:02:01

Comment: @Sammitch , https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472632/1492649